# React Native vs WPA apps experience so far

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I have a medium size project on React+Nodejs and I need to choose best suitable technology for the mobile part. I am considering React Native or Web Progressive Apps for that. I want to ask you guys what is your experience so far about performance of "native-like" React Native versus WPA based apps.

I need to put into consideration:
1. Making it as easy as possible to make a transfer from ReactJS code into mobile.
2. Hardware support on mobile devices. Such as Barcode reading and NFC.
3. Push notifications.
4. Function well on both Android and iOS.

Biggest question is whether WPA technology has already become mature enough to trust it or not.

Comment: `This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.` https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: what if I ask: will I feel lack of functionality and performance speed in WPA compared to React Native?

Comment: @ZUNJAE I would see this question as asking for capabilities and limitations of PWA comparing to native which is a straight question and doesn't leads to wage discussions violating SO terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make the same decision couple of months back and we chose PWA (not the answer for everyone yet).

**Here is why we chose PWA,**

**1) Performance** - [Web can now perform 60fps](https://www.testufo.com/) - The magic number needs for native like smooth transitions.

**2) Cost** - Its fast and easy to build a product for both as a mobile app and web using PWA with no learning curve for existing web developers. 
3) Proven - Starting from [Twitter lite](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2017/twitter) to Flipkart, there are so many success stories on PWA. No doubt its reliable. With iOS support coming couple of months back, now all major browsers support it.

**PWA limitations and workarrounds,**

**1) Hardware** - PWAs are limited to [what web can do today](https://whatwebcando.today/). So there are hardwares like bar-code scanner we don't have any scope of support anytime soon and there are some hardware which very limited support and some hardware like Bluetooth with average support(in terms of % of browser versions supporting today) We had to build a small Android Native application to interact with these hardware and pass on the info to PWA suing web sockets. Say, when a barcode is scanned, this native Android service will listen for and receive it and pass on to our PWA. Same thing goes to NFC.

**2) Packing and deploying** - There is no official way to generate an APK and distribute in corporate environment. We were able to extract the APK after adding the PWA app to home screen using some file explorer and use that to distribute though. Havent tried on iOS. Hope for latest versions for any mobile OS, we can use cordova(not pure PWA but we get most of the benefits like Service Worker) to package and distribute as well.